# Run cdp commands on Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chrome-devtools-protocol

Selenium seems to have a method `driver.execute_cdp_cmd` but I cannot find any `executeCdpCommand` for Chrome web driver in C# version of selenium library, Anyone knows where or how we can run such commands like the below code in python (I want the same on C# .NET):

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
  "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })
  """
})

driver.get(some_url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V96.Page;
using Network = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V96.Network;
using DevToolsSessionDomains = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V96.DevToolsSessionDomains;


IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
            DevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
            var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();
            domains.Page.Enable(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V96.Page.EnableCommandSettings());
domains.Page.AddScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument(new AddScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocumentCommandSettings()
        {
            Source = "Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', { get: () => undefined })"
        });
```

Comment: Syntax Error -  domains.Page.Enable ...  'DevToolsSessionDomains' does not contain a definition for 'Page' and no accessible extension method 'Page' accepting a first argument of type 'DevToolsSessionDomains' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: You have to edit the `V96` to any version available on your current Selenium library you used for example V115 or ... for the newer library, you can check which versions available on your Selenium then using that.